# Website with editor and a preview

Tags: web, web-development-server

I'd like to create a website with some kind of editor. The editor gives options to manipulate a picture which is then send to the server on which a Python programm does the work.

I'd like to add a preview of the picture in that editor which updates automatically when the users does changes or if that's the better way triggers an update.

I've already seen such editors but I'm too new in web development to know what I should use for that.

Could someone give me a hint as what I should look for or which frameworks I could use?

I'd really appreciate some hints which pushes me into the right direction.

Comment: `Editor` is too broad.

Comment: What do you mean with too broad? I'm unsure how to call it otherwhise.

Comment: Editor could mean `applying filters`, `draw with color`, `change size`, `convert file formats`, `type text` etc.. The differences are quite big so you should specify what kind of `editor` you are talking about.

Comment: Well it's a very simple tool which changes e.g. size, and colors. I want to learn how to do something like this with some basic ideas and then add more functionality later on. 

I'm very new to web development and unsure what to look for. I've got the feeling Ajax would be the right choice but then i think it's not.